# Validate url with extensios at the end using regular expression

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

How to validate the below url's which is ending with extensions like .mp4 or .wmv

And also starting with http or https or www

Example:

```
http://media.ch9.ms/ch9/360b/74fd8811-951f-40aa-bc24-91d51b82360b/Search.mp4
https://media.ch9.ms/ch9/360b/74fd8811-951f-40aa-bc24-91d51b82360b/Search.mp4
www.media.ch9.ms/ch9/360b/74fd8811-951f-40aa-bc24-91d51b82360b/Search.mp4
```

Comment: used the below expression http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&amp;=]*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More readable:

```
^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www\.).*(\.mp4|\.mkv)$
```

More concise:

```
^(http(s)?:\/\/|www\.).*(\.mp4|\.mkv)$
```

Demo:

> https://regex101.com/r/wK2rV0/1

Explanation:

- First group verifies that the line starts "^" matching "http://"(with optional: https) or www.
- in the middle, ".*", any given character different to newline
- the last group, it must match or mp4 or mkv at the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^(http[s]?:\/\/)?([^:\/\s]+)(:([^\/]*))?(\/\w+\.)*([^#?\s]+)(\?([^#]*))?(\.mp4|\.mkv)$/gm
```

see demo here https://regex101.com/r/vL1gZ5/2